# Karma - Expected undefined to equal

Tags: angularjs, testing, karma-jasmine

I've got my mock window object and method:

```
var window = {
    open: function (url, target, specs) {
        var spec, specKey;
        this.href = url;
        this.target = target;
        // Parse through the spec string to grab the parameters you passed through
        var specArray = specs.split(',');
        for (specKey in specArray) {
            spec = specArray[specKey].split('=');
            this[String.trim(spec[0])] = String.trim(spec[1]);
        }
    }
};
```

and my test case:

```
describe('$scope.popup1', function () {

    it('should open a popup window when ISIN hyperlink is clicked within grid, passing ISIN object s values to shareDataService', inject(function ($window) {
        spyOn($window, 'open').and.callFake(function () {
            return true;
        });
        scope.popup1()
        expect(window.open).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(window.open.href).toEqual("views/Box_Ladder.html");
    })
   )
})
```

But I get `Expected undefined to equal 'views/Box_Ladder.html'`.  I'm not sure how window.open.href is undefined seeing as I declared it above?

EDIT - updated code, still same error:

```
describe('mainCtrl', function () {

beforeEach(module('app'));
var controller, scope;
var window = {
    open: function (url, target, specs) {
console.log("function being called")
        var spec, specKey;
        this.href = url;
        this.target = target;
        // Parse through the spec string to grab the parameters you passed through
        var specArray = specs.split(',');
        for (specKey in specArray) {
            spec = specArray[specKey].split('=');
            this[String.trim(spec[0])] = String.trim(spec[1]);
        }
    }
};

beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $window, $rootScope) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    controller = $controller('mainCtrl', {$scope: scope});
    window = $window;
}));

describe('$scope.popup1', function () {

    it('should open a popup window when ISIN hyperlink is clicked within grid, passing ISIN object s values to shareDataService', inject(function ($window) {
        spyOn($window, 'open').and.callThrough()
        scope.popup1()
        expect(window.open).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(window.href).toEqual("views/Box_Ladder.html");
        //expect(window.location.target).toEqual("_blank");
        //expect(window.location.height).toEqual(400);
        //expect(window.width).toEqual(700);
    })
   )
})
});
```

And popup1() function:

```
$scope.popup1 = function (isinData) {
    var popup1 = window.open("views/Box_Ladder.html", "_blank",
                        "height = 400, width = 700");
    shareDataService.setIsinClickValue(isinData);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In `open` function `this` is referring to `window` object, not the function itself, so try this:

```
expect(window.href).toEqual("views/Box_Ladder.html");
```

More info about `this` here: [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Also, you have used `callFake` which according to the docs is:

> Spies: andCallFake
>
> By chaining the spy with andCallFake, all calls to the spy will delegate to the supplied function.

You can either register your implementation as fake function or use `callThrough` which is calling real implementation (or the one that you have mocked before).

You can find all details in Jasmine docs: http://jasmine.github.io/

Comment: Yeah this was how I originally had it, but same result :(

Comment: Edited the answer - I hope now it should help you.

Comment: This seems to have done the trick somewhat, the popup is opening.  However I still get `Expected undefined to equal 'views/Box_Ladder.html'.` in console

Comment: Please edit your question and add current code below original question

Comment: Firts, with callThrough you don't pass any function, so: `spyOn($window, 'open').and.callThrough();`. Then make sure your mocked function is being called - in debug or by adding simple console.log with some message. Please also add code for `$scope.popup1()` and show how do you initialize scope itself in the test code.

Comment: I've now included my whole test file and popup1() method with the included changes.  I see no output for my `console.log()` :S

Comment: Look at this: `window = $window;`. I think that might be the case if the function is not being call at all. Try to add it in beforeEach like `$window.open = function (...) {...}.`